# pig - transform data from mutilple rows to columns using Pig

Tags: apache-pig-grunt

I am running into an issue while trying to transform the data from long form to wide.

My input file :

```
Id1   
Name1   
Mail1   
Id2   
Name2   
Mail2
```

I want the data to be transformed like

```
Id1 Name1 Mail1 
Id2 Name2 Mail2
```